# Copy files and folders from Azure DataLake Gen1 to Azure DataLake Gen2 without Azure DataFactory

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

We want to migrate data from Azure DataLake Gen1 to Azure DataLake Gen2 and we don't want to use Azure DataFactory, is there any way to copy data using azcopy/AdlCopy/Azure Storage Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

No, azcopy, AdlCopy and Azure Storage Explorer don't support copy data from ADL Gen1 to ADL Gen2.

[azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy#synopsis) supports directions are these:

- local <-> Azure Blob (SAS or OAuth authentication)
- local <-> Azure Files (Share/directory SAS authentication)
- local <-> Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 (SAS, OAuth, or shared key
  authentication)
- Azure Blob (SAS or public) -> Azure Blob (SAS or OAuth
  authentication)
- Azure Blob (SAS or public) -> Azure Files (SAS)
- Azure Files (SAS) -> Azure Files (SAS)
- Azure Files (SAS) -> Azure Blob (SAS or OAuth authentication)
- Amazon Web Services (AWS) S3 (Access Key) -> Azure Block Blob (SAS or
  OAuth authentication)

[AdlCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob):

- From Azure Storage blobs into Data Lake Storage Gen1. You can't use
  AdlCopy to copy data from Data Lake Storage Gen1 to Azure Storage
  blobs.
- Between two Data Lake Storage Gen1 accounts.

If you want to copy data without using ADF, you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-migrate-gen1-to-gen2).

Comment: How we can copy files from Azure DataLake Gen1 to Local using command line ?